# How I can get the complete URL by using NEPacketTunnelProvider?

Tags: ios, vpn, packet

By using **NEPacketTunnelProvider** I am able to get the destination host address, but I can not get the complete URL, is there any possibility that I can get the complete URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to capturing a HTTP request path, you will need to *sniff* each `Data` packet by parsing each header until you get to the HTTP layer and determine the request path. It would likely take a bit of work to develop the packet parsing structure in Swift, and wouldn't work with HTTPS.